# Copy files from non-booting VPS

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, vps, vnc, upgrade

It’s a good thing this is my ‘practice’ server, rather than a production server…

I have a VPS that was running Ubuntu 16.04. I started an upgrade to 16.04.1 LTS – and then I lost my SSH connection when there was a dialog on screen.

I tried

```
sudo screen -D -r
```

No luck.

After some googling, I followed the top answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/346678/how-do-i-resume-a-release-upgrade :

```
sudo apt-get install -f

sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Lots of installation and configuration scrolled by for about an hour.

The VPS still worked, though very slowly, so I did...

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

The VPS no longer boots.
I used the VPS-provider’s control panel to mount a Linux Mint ISO, and I can boot that, and VNC into it. I can see my VPS file-system.

When I attempt to SSH to the VPS, the connection is refused.

**My question is this…**

How can I copy some files from the non-booting VPS to my Win10 PC?

**Oh, and a bonus question too…**

I’m going to copy the files off, then reinstall the VPS.
However, if I didn’t want to reinstall, is there a noob way to reliably revive this VPS to full function?

Answer (score 0):

From here I can't see what's going wrong with your VPS and why you can't open a SSH session to your bootable Mint. Be sure the ssh service is running and listening to port 22. However, if you have a working internet connection on your Mint OS, you can upload the files you need as example over FTP to an external server.

How to recover your VPS, that's a question I can't answer with the info you gave. Maybe you can find anything in your server logs. Success!